# How to enable or disable Button control on entering true regular expression validator in asp.net using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on an application.In this application a have a textbox on which i have applied a calender extender to enter Date. i have also applied a regular expression validator to enter Date in Indian format.I have a button to select all the data on the Date entered in the textbox.I have done that as:-

```
<table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Select Date :
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="cc" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDate" ></asp:CalendarExtender>

                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
                                            SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Ad" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Date" Display="Dynamic">
                                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
                                            SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Ad" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"
                                            ErrorMessage="Invalid Date.">
                                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                        <ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbeDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" ValidChars="0123456789/.">
                                        </ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Font-Bold="true" CssClass="btn-info" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

I want that if user enters correct Date in textbox then the button should gets enabled else it should gets disabled.i don't know know how to do that.please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="cc" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtDate" ></ajax:CalendarExtender>

                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
                                            SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Ad" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Date" Display="Dynamic">
                                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
                                            SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Ad" ValidationExpression="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"
                                            ErrorMessage="Invalid Date.">
                                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                        <ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbeDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" ValidChars="0123456789/.">
                                        </ajax:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```

and you need to add this code in code behind:

```
protected void txtDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = txtDate.Text;

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            btnSubmit.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. But i want this to perform using jquery if possible.Thanx in adv.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding the following script (You will need  to add Jquery to your project):

```
$(function (){

 $("btnSubmit").prop('disabled', true);

 $("#txtDate").change(function(){

      var pageIsValid =  Page_ClientValidate();

     $("btnSubmit").prop('disabled', !pageIsValid);

  });

});
```

Comment: which type of jquery should i add?